# Finder File Sharing: How to access the hard disk?

Tags: network, finder, file-sharing, afp

I use an iMac and a MacBook in my local network. I want to access the iMac's hard disk from the MacBook via the Finder's File Sharing.

On both the Macs, I have a user account with the same name and password. Both accounts have local administrator rights.

If I connect from the MacBook to the iMac using with the Finder, I can only see and access the Home directory of the user on the iMac whose credentials I entered. I cannot see or access other directories like `/Applications/`.

How can I access all contents of the iMac's hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the option "Share files and folders using SMB" has to be enabled. If it is enabled, the Finder automatically lists all hard disks and the user folder from the remote mac when connected.

[image: Sharing Settings]

Answer (score 1):

The system folders are not shared over the network by default. Go to System Preferences app → Sharing and enable File Sharing.

Now under **Shared Folders**, click on the `+` button and add the desired folders.

[image]

Comment: As per [this Apple Help Page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25605?locale=en_US), adding folders this way shouldn't be necessary: "_A user with an administrator account can access your entire Mac._"